# R tools (RTVS) causes Visual Studio 2017 to crash

Tags: r, visual-studio-2017, rtvs

I have recently installed R tools (RTVS) for Visual Studio 2017

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/rtvs/installing-r-tools-for-visual-studio

I am running version 15.5.6 of Visual Studio 2017.

The installation of the R tools addin appeared to be successful.  However, whenever I attempt to create a new R project template via Visual Studio it crashes with the following fault exception:

Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 15.0.27130.2027, time stamp: 0x5a6aa180
Faulting module name: ucrtbase.dll, version: 10.0.14393.1770, time stamp: 0x59bf2b5a
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x00087fb2
Faulting process id: 0x23f0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3a0213174216c
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll
Report Id: ebed811f-1841-48db-8dca-251cedb31ab0
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Has anyone else had similar issues?  Are there any known fixes for this?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you find a work-around?

Comment: No sorry I had no luck with this.

Comment: Try updating VS to version 15.7.5 and then installing .Net framework version 4.7.2 - from [this topic on the MS developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/248068/r-tools-stop-working-after-1570-upgrade.html). This worked for me.